# EF Object entity State moves to Unchanged when attached to new Context

Tags: linq, entity-framework, save

I have go the oddest problem, I get an object from EF and pass it back to the Business Logic for manipulation, when finished i'm trying to save the object back to the DB, when the object is passed into the following method it's EntityState is Modified but as soon as the attach line of code is run it is set to UnChanged hence the Save will not work.

Does anyone know why EF would do this?

```
    public void Save(IEntity entity)
    {
        using (var context = new eDocumentEntities())
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                if (entity.Id != 0)
                    context.AttachTo(entity.EntitySet, entity);
                else
                    context.AddObject(entity.EntitySet, entity);
                context.SaveChanges();
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution to the problem here but Ii'm more interested in an explanation, why would EF do this, seems very counter productive!?

http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/11/27/attaching-modified-entities-in-ef-4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since entity change tracking  is encapsulated in Context, naturally the entity loses state and other tracking stuff when it gets detached from context.

Comment: Ohhh I thought it was encapsulated in the objcet it's self not the context.  Thanks.